# Using methods in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to call a method within javascript for loop , I am able to iterate through the method body but the method gets executed with the last iterated record .

Eg . I am getting data from a service call .

```
if(data.length != 0){  
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
        if(data[i].serviceId=='webservice1'){
            CustomerData=data[i].customerdata;
            GlobalProject.CurrentCustomerData(CustomerData);
        }
    }
}
```

Here , CurrentCustomerData method gets called with the last value of CustomerData in the for loop .

Comment: Could you post a sample of `data` ?

Comment: Your question is not having sufficient data to answer. Can you also provide the details about what `data` array holds. I could see a condition getting applied before calling `CurrentCustomerData`, so there is probability that there could be only one record matching that condition.

Comment: The data is in the forms of array object . eg [object,object ,object]where all the three objects will be in the form of : "serviceId":"CI","name";"Sample1" and so on . Please do let me know if u want the exact data .